# How to use Scala annotations in Java code

Tags: java, scala, reflection, annotations, scala-reflect

Is there any way to use annotations defined in Scala so they can work with Java code? I have a library with some annotations I would like to use in Java

Comment: It depends. Most probably no. What library, what annotations, how to "work"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quotes from scaladocs:

> A base class for annotations.
>     Annotations extending this class directly are not preserved in the classfile. To enable storing
>    annotations in the classfile's Scala signature and make it available to Scala reflection and
>    other tools, the annotation needs to inherit from [[scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation]].
>     **Annotation classes defined in Scala are not stored in classfiles in a Java-compatible manner
>     and therefore not visible in Java reflection.** In order to achieve this, the annotation has to
>     be written in Java.
>
> `abstract class Annotation`

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/annotation/Annotation.scala

> A base class for static annotations. These are available to the Scala
>   type checker or Scala  reflection, even across different compilation
>   units.  **Annotation classes defined in Scala are not stored in
>   classfiles in a Java-compatible manner  and therefore not visible in
>   Java reflection.** In order to achieve this, the annotation has to  be
>   written in Java.
>
> `trait StaticAnnotation extends Annotation`

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/annotation/StaticAnnotation.scala