# How to access scala annotation in scala code

Tags: scala, reflection, annotations, scala-reflect

I have defined a simple scala annoation and use it to annotate my case class Person:

```
package com.my

import  scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation

@scala.annotation.meta.field
class Description(value: String) extends StaticAnnotation{

}
```

Then I use it in my Person class:

```
package com.my

import scala.beans.BeanProperty

case class Person(

                   @Description(value = "name00")
                   name: String,

                   @Description(value = "age00")
                   age: Int,

                   @BeanProperty
                   xyz: String = "xyz"
                 )

object Person {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val p = Person("abc", 21)
    classOf[Person].getDeclaredFields.foreach {
      field =>
        field.setAccessible(true)
        val name = field.getName
        val value = field.get(p)
        //annotations always return empty array
        val annotations = field.getDeclaredAnnotations
        annotations.foreach {
          annotation =>
            val tpe = annotation.annotationType()
            println(tpe)
        }
        println(s"name is $name, value is: $value")
    }
  }
}
```

In the main method of Person object, the annotations array is always empty,
I would like to ask how to get the annoation information defined on the field.

Comment: Why do you need those annotations? Maybe you can solve your original problem in a simpler / cleaner way.

Comment: Scala annotations are different than Java annotations, you use use Scala Reflection API to access them.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez. I just use this simple code to illustrate my problem here, the key point is that I want to use scala annotation, thanks.

Comment: @Tom Why is it important to use Scala annotation? Can you use Java annotation? (Anyway you use Java reflection, not Scala reflection.)

Comment: @Tom Anyway if it's important that `@Description` is Scala annotation see update of my answer with Scala reflection.

Answer (score 2):

**Firstly,** annotations written in Scala are accessible in sources (if the annotations extend `scala.annotation.Annotation`) and class files (if if the annotations extend `scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation`). In order to be accessible at runtime the annotations must be written in Java

```java
import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Description {
    String value();
}
```

[How to use Scala annotations in Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57589952/how-to-use-scala-annotations-in-java-code)

[Why annotations written in Scala are not accessible at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38647213/why-annotations-written-in-scala-are-not-accessible-at-runtime)

https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/81qzs2/how_to_write_annotations_in_scala/

Alternatively you can use the original `@Description` (written in Scala and extending `StaticAnnotation`) but then you have to access it at runtime via [Scala reflection](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html) rather than Java reflection.

**Secondly,** you misuse meta-annotations (`@scala.annotation.meta.field`). They should annotate not the definition of `@Description` but its applications.

```scala
import scala.annotation.meta.field

case class Person(
                   @(Description @field)(value = "name00")
                   name: String,

                   @(Description @field)(value = "age00")
                   age: Int,

                   @BeanProperty
                   xyz: String = "xyz"
                 )
```

[Annotating case class parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51485956/annotating-case-class-parameters)

[How can I reflect on a field annotation (Java) in a Scala program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59620528/how-can-i-reflect-on-a-field-annotation-java-in-a-scala-program)

[Calling a method from Annotation using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62343008/calling-a-method-from-annotation-using-reflection)

Output:

```
interface Description // appears
name is name, value is: abc
interface Description // appears
name is age, value is: 21
name is xyz, value is: xyz
```

---

With Scala reflection you can do

```scala
import scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation
import scala.beans.BeanProperty
import scala.annotation.meta.field
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

class Description(value: String) extends StaticAnnotation

case class Person(
                   @(Description @field)(value = "name00")
                   name: String,

                   @(Description @field)(value = "age00")
                   age: Int,

                   @BeanProperty
                   xyz: String = "xyz"
                 )

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val p = Person("abc", 21)
  typeOf[Person].decls
    .collect { case t: TermSymbol if t.isVal => t.annotations }
    .foreach(println)
}

//List(Description @scala.annotation.meta.field("name00"))
//List(Description @scala.annotation.meta.field("age00"))
//List(scala.beans.BeanProperty)
```